# Binding accepting enums that conform to one protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two enums that conform to one protocol, an observable object that holds arrays of those enums and a view that I want to accept both enums.

The observable object:

```swift
class OptionsStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var topicOptions: [TopicOption]
    @Published var levelOptions: [LevelOption]
}
```

One of the enums and the protocol:

```swift
enum TopicOption: String, CaseIterable, OptionCompatible {
    case music, food, traffic

    ...
}

protocol OptionCompatible {
    ...
}
```

The views:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var optionsStore: OptionsStore

    var body: some View {
        OptionsView(
            options: TopicOption.allCases,                   // no error
            activeOptions: self.$optionsStore.topicOptions   // error
        )
    }
}

struct OptionsView: View {
    let options: [OptionCompatible]
    @Binding var activeOptions: [OptionCompatible]
}
```

The error is

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[TopicOption]>' to expected argument type 'Binding<[OptionCompatible]>'

What I want is the `OptionsView` to accept both enums. Why does it go well by calling the static `allCases`, but not when I pass an array of those enums? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the difference between these two lines:

```
options: TopicOption.allCases,                   // no error
activeOptions: self.$optionsStore.topicOptions   // error
```

is that the first one does not involve a `Binding`. Normally an array of subtypes can be assigned to a variable of the type of an array of supertypes. This is not true for `Binding<[Subtype]>` and `Binding<[Supertype]>`.

This is because not only does a `Binding` needs to *get* the value that you pass in. It also *sets* it. Recall the common scenario of passing a `Binding<String>` to a `TextField`. The value of the `Binding` will change when the user enters text, right?

`OptionsView` declares a `Binding<[OptionCompatible]>`. This is saying that it might add some kind of `OptionCompatible` type to the array. But you are passing it a `[TopicOptions]`! If `OptionsView` wants to add a `LevelOption` to the array, for example, it can't!

You might say "but I am sure my `OptionsView` will only add objects of the correct type!" Well, the way to say this to the compiler is to make `OptionsView` generic:

```
struct OptionsView<OptionType: OptionCompatible>: View {
    let options: [OptionType]
    @Binding var activeOptions: [OptionType]

}
```

Comment: This was fantastically helpful, and allowed me to clean up some vexing code that had been giving me grief. Thank you!